# d3.js Multiple trees same root

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I want to create two trees that share the same root. In my hierarchical JSON file, I have the root parent and two children attributes named left and right. One of the children branches out to make the right tree and the other makes the left tree. On the left side of the root, I want the nested left children to only expand and only right nested children to expand on the right. The root of the tree is the only node that expands both left and right children.

```
var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "left": [
      {
        "name": "Left 1",
        "left": [
          {
            "name": "Left 1 left Child 1",
          },
          {
            "name": "Left 1 left Child 2",
          }
        ],
        "right": [
          {
            "name": "Left 1 right Child 1",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Left 2",
        "left": [

        ],
        "right": [
          {
            "name": "Left 2 right Child 1",
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "right": [
      {
        "name": "Right 1",
        "left": [
          {
            "name": "Right 1 left Child 1",
          },
          {
            "name": "Right 1 left Child 2",
          }
        ],
        "right": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Right 2",
        "left": [

        ],
        "right": [
          {
            "name": "Right 2 right Child 1",
          }

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

This should display a tree diagram: [image: Tree]

How exactly would I go about implementing this? I thought of drawing two trees sharing the same parent root and just flipping the depth of the right:

```
var leftTree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width])
  .children(function(d){return d.left;});//this will provide right children.
var rightTree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width])
  .children(function(d){return d.right;});//this will provide right children.

    // Call update function with tree parameter, Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { 
                   if(tree == rightTree) { 
                       d.y = d.depth * 90; 
                   } else { //tree is left tree
                       d.y = - d.depth * 90;}});
```

I then call my function update (similar to: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8323795), on both leftTree and rightTree. The only problem with this is when I draw links which I believe has to do with assigning id's to nodes.

```
    // Declare the nodes
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });
    ...
    // Declare the links…
      var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
          .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

      // Enter the links.
      link.enter().insert("path", "g")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("d", diagonal);
```

Here is the result: 
[image: Tree]
I feel like I am close but drawing the links gets messed up.

 Would it be easier if I change the structure of my JSON file to include both left and right children in an overall children attribute and then add some kind of conditional when creating the nodes that only draws nodes that are on their respected side? For example, when drawing the left subtree, I look at all the children of root "Top Level" and draw the nodes in the "left" attribute, then draw the left nodes left nested children. Then, draw the right subtree with the children in the right attribute and their nested right children.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

I had faced the similar problem and created a sample file. This should help you [Double side tree using D3JS](https://github.com/palanikumarr/d3js-doubleside-tree).